# c++ take half-word from integer variable when displayed in hex

Tags: c++, hex

I have an integer

```
int value = 0x12345678;
```

I want to take the first half and the second half and place the two halves into two separate integers
e.g.

```
int value2 = 0x1234;
int value3 = 0x5678;
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shift the number by 16 bits to the right to get the first half.

```
int value2 = (value >> 16);
```

Use bitwise `&` to get the second half.

```
int value3 = (value & 0xFFFF);
```

Comment: Careful. Your description assumes that this is on a little-endian machine. --
Also, this calculation of `value2` will not work correctly for negative `value`.

Comment: @geipel, while your concern about negative values is valid, your concern about endianness is not. Bit shift operators and bitwise operators must work independent of endianness.

Answer (score 0):

Note that I changed this to using unsigned (to avoid sign-extension on 32-bit platforms for arbitrary values of `value1`)

```
unsigned value1 = 0x12345678;
unsigned value2 = value1 / 0x10000;
unsigned value3 = value1 % 0x10000;
```

I chose this method -- only caring about the int values here.

If you take care about the representation, you can also use shift operators and masks.